# Cardinality of the set $D$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let , $D$ be the set of tuples $(w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_{10})$ , where $w_i \in \{1,2,3\},1\le i\le10$ and $w_i+w_{i+1}$ is an even number for each $i$ with $1\le i\le 9$.

Then find the cardinality of $D$.

As , $w_i+w_{i+1}$ is an even number so either both even OR both odd. Again $w_i\in \{1,2,3\}$. So , both even possibility is exactly $1$ which is $(2,2,\cdots,2)$.

But I am unable to find the both odd possibility..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every sequence of 1's and 3's satisfies the properties above (since, as you pointed out, the sum of two odd numbers is even). Thus, you simply need to ask how many distinct sequences of 1's and 3's there are with 10 elements. Notice that this is the same as the number of functions which map from $\{w_1,...,w_{10}\}$ into $\{1, 3\}$. The number of such functions is $$|\{1,3\}|^{|\{w_1,...,w_{10}\}|}=2^{10} = 1024$$

Since no sequence with both even and odd elements is an element of $D$, we have exhausted both lists. Therefore, $D = $ odd sequences $+$ even sequences. Finally, $D = 1024 + 1 = 1025$